# Folium to display points in Leaflet map (from data stored in array)

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I'm attempting to use Folium to create a web map using Leaflet with data stored in an array. However, the markers are not being added to the map.

I'm using the code below.

```
centerX = 34.2104
centerY = -77.8868
coord = [centerX, centerY]
m = folium.Map(coord, zoom_start=13)
m.save("index.html")
marker = []
with open(userInFile, 'r') as ds:
    i=0
    for line in ds:
        i+=1
        strippedLine = line.strip()
        lineList = strippedLine.split(',')

        if i > 1:
            x = lineList[16]
            y = lineList[17]
            marker.append(x)
            marker.append(y)
# Add markers to map
print(marker)
i = 0
while i < len(marker)-1:
    folium.Marker([float(marker[i]), float(marker[i+1])], popup="new location", icon=folium.Icon(color="green")).add_to(m)
    print(marker[i], marker[i+1])
    i+=2
```

I wanted to make sure the data was being added to array correctly, below is the output of the print statements.

[image]

But none of the markers are being added to the map, only the basemap shows up. Where is my error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `m.save("index.html")` to the end.

```
# previous lines

while i < len(marker)-1:
    folium.Marker([float(marker[i]), float(marker[i+1])], popup="new location", icon=folium.Icon(color="green")).add_to(m)
    print(marker[i], marker[i+1])
    i+=2

m.save("index.html")
```